# How to calculation the Hausdorff dimension of this set?

Tags: real-analysis, fractals, dimension-theory-analysis, hausdorff-measure, fractal-analysis

It's about Exercise 1.19, Fractals in Probability and Analysis?

> Suppose $S\subset\mathbb{N}$, and we are given $E,F\subset\{0,1,2\}$. Define $B_S=\{x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k2^{-k}\}$ where $x_k\in E$ if $k\in S$ and $x_k\in F$ otherwise.

The Hausdorff dimension $\dim(B_S)$ in terms of $E,F,S$ is asked to be calculated.

I learn how to calculate the Hausdorff dimension of some symmetric set, i.e if I scale or translate it, It's similar to itself such as Canton sets. But this exercise gives a different set. Could someone give me some hints/solutions?

Comment: Please look at our guidelines for [formatting and writing](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992) your post, in particular this: *Don't force someone to click on an external link just to see or understand your question, it should be immediately visible after clicking on your title.*

Comment: Let me also suggest our guidelines for [avoiding "I don't know how to solve it" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: @LeeMosher My apologize. I'll correct it asap.

Comment: Are you sure that  $E,F\subseteq \{0,1,2 \}$? This is essentially a binary representation of numbers, so it seems natural that they would be subsets of $\{ 0,1 \}$.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Yes I'm sure. Actually this is also the point that I don't know how to handle.